# Relating PHP to source files

Tags: php, html

Sorry if the title is a bit vague, couldn't think of a better way to phrase it, anyway.

I'm attempting to make a page system for a website. Where you predictably start on page one, and then click page two and a different set of images appear. Each page has 12 images which are all thumbnail images. You click on the thumbnail image and lightbox brings up the high res shot. 
My current problem is that I cannot link the PHP script to the images correctly. To me it looks correct but it doesn't work, so clearly not.

Info:
Thumbnails are name "thumb1.jpg" from 1-24, full images are name "img1.jpg" from 1-24

```
<?php
$imgs = array(12, 12, );

if(!empty($_GET["page"]))      
{
  $currPage = $_GET["page"];
}
else
{
  $currPage = 1;
}

for($i = 1; $i<$imgs[$currPage-1]+1;$i++)
{
  echo "<a href='albums/norfolk weekender 2012/img'.$imgs[$currPage][$i].'.jpg' rel='lightbox[group]'><img src='albums/norfolk weekender 2012/thumb'.$imgs[$currPage][$i].'.jpg'/></a>";
}
?>
```

. 
Anyway, I'm unsure why it doesn't work, and any help will be much appreciated.
Ta.
John.

Comment: To format, highlight the code block and ctl-k, or click the `{ }` button.  4 spaces indentation forms a code block.

Comment: PHP probably won't care but remove the trailing `,` after the second `12,` in the array declaration. While it won't fail in PHP, it _will_ fail in other languages and is thus a bad habit to be in

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Actually it is often preferred to leave it in. Even more so when doing multi/lines array declarations. For one version control diff would not think the line has changed.

Comment: Use some simple math to determine the first and last image number (with one-based page and index, `$first = ($currPage - 1) * $pageLength + 1; $last = $first + $pageLength - 1;`), loop over that range and output a link with each number. Take care not to output a link to an image that doesn't exist.

Comment: @PeeHaa based on experience here seeing it break JavaScript object declarations in IE only over and over, and cause SQL syntax errors in the `SELECT` list, I would rather never see it anywhere... Fair enough though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'.$imgs[$currPage][$i].'
```

It looks like you should be using `"` instead of `'` to wrap round this embedded variable both times you reference it in the code, since your echo is distinguished by `"`.

Either way, looking at this it doesn't seem this array structure you've got going on is working.

```
"albums/norfolk weekender 2012/img".$imgs[$currPage][$i].".jpg"
```

Have you not considered something like this (care, it's rough); with `$pageNo` representing `$_GET["page"]`

```
for ( $i = ($pageNo - 1) * 12 + 1; $i <= ($pageNo * 12); $i++ )
{
    echo "<a href='albums/norfolk weekender 2012/img".$i.".jpg' rel='lightbox[group]'><img src='albums/norfolk weekender 2012/thumb".$i.".jpg'/></a>";
}
```

If presentation (i.e. checking to see if an image exists before displaying it) is a major concern, you could use `file_exists( filename )`. By creating an `Array` like this...

```
$imgs = array(12, 12, );
```

...you are simply creating an array containing two elements of 12 (and possibly a blank element, I'm not entirely sure.) I think where you went wrong is you attempted to declare the size in the "constructor" of `Array`; in PHP this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately no change

Comment: Can you give me the URL that the PHP is producing?

Comment: I've tried to sort out the pagination in the for loop declaration. If this answer is sufficient you should accept it as the correct one (not **entirely** for reputation; but because it signifies the question is answered.)